# Generating new sources via Maven plugin after compile phase

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, pom.xml

I have a Maven project within which I need execute two code generation steps. One generates some Java types, then the second depends on those Java types to generate some more code. Is there a way to have both of these steps happening during my build?

At the moment my steps are:

1. execute first code generation plugin (during `generate-sources`)
2. add directory of generated types to build path
3. execute second code generation plugin (during `compile`)

However my problem is that anything generated by the second code generation plugin will not be compiled (because the compile phase has finished). If I attach the second code generation plugin to an earlier phase, it fails because it needs the classes from the first code generation plugin to be present on the classpath.

**I know I could split this into two modules with one dependent on the other**, but I was wondering if this could be achieved in one pom. It seems like a need a way to invoke compile again after the normal compile phase is complete.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always configure two executions of the compiler plugin, both tied to the compile phase. In one you include the extra stuff:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>one</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration></configuration>
    </execution>  
    <execution>
      <id>two</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-verbose -bootclasspath ${java.home}\lib\rt.jar</compilerArgument>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
<plugin>
```

You may try as well  `<includes><include>path/</include></includes>`

According the [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html):

> When multiple executions are given that match a particular phase, they are executed in the order specified in the POM, with inherited executions running first.

But I quite not get what you exactly want.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Udo - you're raised an interesting alternative that I hadn't considered. I think your formatting has got a little messed up though, for clarity could you correct it?

Comment: @ssedano: Is the execution order guaranteed?

Comment: @AaronDigulla see my addition.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution (generate code after the compile phase) doesn't work since Maven doesn't allow to reorder the phases.

The correct solution is to use [modules](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects). You need two: The first module contains the code generator. In the second module, you can use the generator from the first module to generate something in the `generate-sources` phase.

The big advantage of this approach: You can never get caught in some kind of loop (like "A" needs generated code which needs "A"). So your build will be more simple and you will spend less time hunting odd bugs.

**[UPDATE]** In my projects, I run the code generator from tests. Without a special option, the files are generated into the temp folder and compared to the sources. That allows me to see when I have unexpected changes in my generated code ([which I put under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880876/34088)).

When the system property is set, the source files are overwritten and I can commit the changes to my VCS.

Comment: How can I bind to the generate-sources phase then? Do I have to write a maven plugin for that?

Comment: @Wudong: A simple Maven module is just a few lines of code but for this to work reliably, you need to move the code generator to a stand-aline project (Maven might not load JARs that are generated while it runs). If that's too much effort, try http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/

Comment: I just had a try and use the maven-exec-plugin to run a Java main class from a dependent module, it works fine, so no stand-alone project is needed after all. thanks for the enlightenment though.