# What should be committed to the repository in the Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, svn, birt

I have a Eclipse installed to work with BIRT reports. What files in the workspace should be committed to the repository and what files should not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, any file able to help a developer checkout the repo and (almost) immediately open the project to work on it.
That should include at least eclipse files like `.project`, `.classpath`, and some IDE settings.
They might be some BIRT-specific settings as well.

See also:

- [Do you keep your project files under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377)
- [When working with Eclipse, should I add the workspace to the source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429125/when-working-with-eclipse-should-i-add-the-workspace-to-the-source-control/1429225#1429225)

Comment: Agreed.  The less configuration developers on your team have to do the better.  For example, my team checks in eclipse specific files such as .project, .classpath, .checkstyle among other files to help bootstrap a developer's environment.  We have other developers using Netbeans and they check in their IDE specific files without the team noticing much.  The cost, i.e. disk space and version control maintenance, is minimal compared to the time gained from skipping their local environment setup.