# Version control ignore list for google app engine Java apps

Tags: java, google-app-engine, version-control

Is there a standard list of files/directories/pattens that can be added to a version control ignore list (e.g. .hgignore) when version controlling the source of a Google app engine Java app?

I guess a bunch of people must have worked this out already, any good examples out there?

Comment: how about GAE jar files, located in war/WEB-INF/lib,.. they are coming along with GAE SDK, and updated each time SDK is updated :) Seen no answers about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with a lack of any obvious answers, I made my own up. Here's the .hgignore I went with, replacing [app-name-here] with the name of the app:

```
syntax: glob
*.class
war/[app-name-here]
war/WEB-INF/classes
```

The [repo](http://bitbucket.org/netmelody/met2rss/src/) is public if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 4):

Standard list, maybe not, but you have [some](http://code.google.com/p/dherbst-app-engine-django/source/browse/.hgignore) [examples](http://code.google.com/p/project-picky/source/browse/.hgignore?r=267f2f8e9b96e52765c97bc0072571d4eccdb7c0):

```
syntax: regexp

\.*py[co]
\.DS_Store
~$
\.coverage
\.egg-info

syntax: glob

nbproject
app.yaml
auth.py
dist
target
WEB-INF/appengine-generated
```

Basically, at least any directory with *generated* content should be ignored.

---

The same principles holds true for *Java* app projects like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/living-stories/source/browse/.hgignore?repo=wordpress) or [that one](https://fedorahosted.org/flies/browser/.hgignore):

```
syntax: glob

*~
*.patch
*.sedbak
*/target/*
*/<project_name>searchindex/*
*/test-output/*

hs_err_pid*.log
tomcat

syntax: regexp
\.jar$

^\.pc/
^.ant-targets-build.xml
\.pages.xml.spdia$
temp-testng-customsuite.xml$

# eclipse and maven stuff
^target

# kde related
\.directory$

#gwt related
^<project_name>-war/war/WEB-INF/classes/
^<project_name>-war/tomcat
\.gwt-tmp$
^<project_name>-war/org.fedorahosted.<project_name>.webtrans.Application
^<project_name>-war/war/org.fedorahosted.<project_name>.webtrans.Application
```

Off course, I will [keep any Eclipse or maven related file under source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024307/what-should-be-committed-to-the-repository-in-the-eclipse-workspace), in order to facilitate the build step when anyone will clone the repo.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion, but it appears to be aimed at Python app-engine apps, and indeed both of the examples you link to are in Python. As stated in the question, I'm working on a Java app.

Comment: @Tom: good point. I have updated my answer with some example of Java app `.hgignore` file.

Answer (score 2):

This should ignore all of the generated files (Used in a .gitignore)

```
gwt-unitCache/
war/<<app-name>>/
war/WEB-INF/classes/
war/WEB-INF/deploy/
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the [maven-gae-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin) and develop within eclipse. This .hgignore I often copy in new projects:

```
\.project
\.classpath
\.settings/
^target$
```

Besides that, you need to consider something else: When you deploy an appengine application, the appengine sdk runtime sends a relation of files to be published along with their checksums, and only updated files are uploaded.

Comment: I don't use maven, and nor do I want to. Also, I don't think you should be ignoring the project classpath and .project settings. These are needed to build the project in eclipse, which people who check-out your code will want to do.

Comment: Maven generates those metadata for you. Thats the reason I put to ignore.