# Should you include or ignore gradle-wrapper.properties

Tags: git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When working on a team of android developers using gradle as your build system. Should you include gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties in git, or should it be part of your .gitignore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should the Gradle Wrapper be committed to VCS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348451/why-should-the-gradle-wrapper-be-committed-to-vcs)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It should be included in your git repo.

By using it with *gradlew*, this will ensure all your developers (and your build servers!) **always** use the same version of Gradle. This way you know that every one is building the same exact way.

Comment: did Android Studio behavior recently change (0.4.4?) with regards to automatically updating gradle-wrapper.properties?  Recently I've been getting prompted to commit changes in the file, which appear to be in the commented out timestamp at the top - see http://goo.gl/sA9hh4 for example.  Don't recall this behavior previously.

Comment: @SeanBarbeau I'm not sure TBH. the fact that the version of Gradle is the same is strange. Shouldn't have changed this.

Answer (score 11):

It should be put under source control, as it's necessary for `gradlew` to work properly.