# Files to include Visual Studio built folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-community

When you want to distribute files from the release\debug folder to other computers as part of an install is there a way to know which files to include to ensure that it does not get run time errors on load? Of the below for example. How do I know which files to include. Is there a report or something I can pull from Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: It has nothing todo with your question... but as a general sugestion... i would add the build output to your git ignore file (looks like you are using git + turtoise git)

Comment: Thanks musium. Are you able to elaborate a bit more please. I am not sure what you mean. :)

Comment: What i mean is: You should not include all files into source control. For example you should exclude your build output. What should be excluded: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1273921/1320170 gitignore for .Net solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2143956/1320170 Ignore files with tortoise: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html