# using VisualSVN server with Tortoise SVN and ankhSVN plugin for visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, ankhsvn

I have a VisualSVN server and the client is TortoiseSVN with AnkhSVN plugin for VS 2008. I created a project in the VS and added the solution to the Subversion through right click and committed it.

In the repository all the folders are present except bin and obj. Why so? Do I have to manually add them from the project folder?

Some people suggested not to add bin and obj to the repository ? Any good reason ?

Comment: Related question: Best general SVN Ignore Pattern? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **never ever** add the 'obj' folder to version control as it is a folder completely managed by MSBuild (which will add and remove files and subdirectories whenever it likes to).

The bin directory should not (note the difference) be versioned as it contains output instead of source files. It is usually better to mark specific files from other places to be copied to the bin directory at build time ("Copy to Output Directory" in Properties Window) then to add files from the bin directory itself.

The Visual Studio project system provides a list of files that should be versioned to SCC providers such as AnkhSVN, and it is this list of files that you see as 'New' in the AnkhSVN pending changes window and commit dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

if you add the bin / obj folders their contents will be marked as read only and you will get compile errors - or certainly I did when I tried it on my setup.

Comment: @pointlesspolitic, why would you want to version you´r dll´s when you can just use code from the repository and build them?