# Can I safely add Bin to the default source ignore list in tfs2010?

Tags: version-control

I'm setting up some experimental builds in TFS2010, and noticed that several patterns I believed were standard practice to ignore are not listed. `*.suo;*.gpstate`

Bin is in the SO exclude [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85353/best-general-svn-ignore-pattern), but perhaps that's a different context that doesn't apply here?

Then I see `Debug;Release` are listed, but not bin (ClientBin which I haven't seen before is).
Is there a good reason I should leave this setting alone and not add `bin` to the list of excluded from source?

Comment: Just so you know ClientBin is used for Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Debug;Release` excludes content of both the bin\Debug, bin\Release and obj\Debug, obj\Release directories. It is smarter to use this and (normally) there is no file content in the obj and bin folders directly.

Answer: you can add bin (and obj) to the list of excluded items, but it will notr give you additional items that are automatically excluded.

p.s. ClientBin does not have Debug\Release subfolders and is therefore excluded using its own name.

Comment: does the ignore list work the same as forbidden patterns policy? regex instead of windows matching.

Comment: No, I do not think so. It is just a file pattern matching algorithm.