# Why is subversion ignoring .cshtml-files by default?

Tags: svn, razor

When I add .cshtml-files to my working copy they show up as 'ignored' by default and I can't figure out why?

This is my ignore-pattern on the affected folders:

> TestResults
>   __MVC_BACKUP
>   *.class *.exe *.dll *.mine *.obj *.ncb *.lib *.log *.idb *.pdb *.ilk .msi .res *.pch *.suo *.exp .~ .~ ~. cvs CVS .CVS .cvs release Release
>   debug Debug ignore Ignore bin Bin obj Obj
>   *.cspkg *.cache
>   *.suo

(Most of it is from this thread [Best general SVN Ignore Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85353/best-general-svn-ignore-pattern))

Comment: Did you check your global [configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2)?

Comment: Yes. It the same. I've recreated it just to make sure.

Comment: What about `svn propget svn:ignore` starting at the directory in question and going all the way up to the root of the working copy?

Comment: Another question: what client are you using to add files?

Comment: Turned out that if I moved all patterns to individual lines it worked just fine :)