# Tortoise SVN - DLL conflicts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am relatively new to using the TortoiseSVN client.  What do you do with binary files e.g. DLLs etc when merging?

Do you simply delete them from the project you are moving to or do you add them to the ignore list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best general SVN Ignore Pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85353/best-general-svn-ignore-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add bin/obj folders to ignore list

Comment: Thanks +1.  This has reduced the conflict list considerably.  The suo file still conflicts.  Is it ok to ignore that?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, [you should ignore it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control)

Answer (score 3):

for bin files usually ignore it.

```
svn propedit
```

Add the following:

```
\src\   
\src\XXX\   
\src\XXX\bin\   
\src\XXX\obj\
```